# Sort_values giving error in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am getting the following eError

TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'

for below line of code

```
print(df.sort_values(by='EmpCount',ascending=True,ignore_index=True))
```

Any suggestion on what could be causing this.

Thanks

Comment: what version of `pandas` are you using

Comment: Adding to @gold_cy: In the pandas docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), it says `ignore_index` is new to version 1.0.0 - check your version